# invalid attempt to call read when READER IS CLOSED .. error repeat at every line

Tags: c#

I am getting this error while i am trying to retrieve data from table.,
I am getting error at every line in while(r1.read()) loop., if i remove that line then i am getting same error in next line, it continues till last line of loop..
Please help.,

```
void otherdata()
    {
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
    
        cmd.CommandText = "select customer.cust_name,customer.cust_id,purchase_details.purchase_id,purchase_details.pdate,purchase_details.subtotal,purchase_details.total,purchase_details.supp_bill_id from Purchase_details inner join customer on purchase_details.supplier_id=customer.cust_id where id =" + pd;

        SqlDataReader r1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (r1.Read())
        {
           

            cbsupplier.Text = r1["cust_name"].ToString();
            txtdate.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(r1["pdate"]);
            txtsubtotal.Text = r1["subtotal"].ToString();
            custid.Text = r1["cust_id"].ToString();

            MessageBox.Show("pochalo");


        }
        r1.Close();
        conn.Close();
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from purchase where purchase_id =" + pd;
        r1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (r1.Read())
        {
            txtadjust.Text = r1["adjustment"].ToString();
            cbtaxrate.Text = r["taxrate"].ToString();
            txttax.Text = r["tax"].ToString();
        }
        conn.Close();
        r1.Close();
      



    }
```

Comment: Not sure what is going on, but you have a bunch of issues with your code: SQL injection, use proper parameters instead. Do not cache connection or command objects, create them when needed. Dispose them and reader objects with `using` blocks. Instead of `Convert.ToDateTime` and `.ToString`, just cast with `(DateTime)` and `(string)`. No need to check connection state, if you closed it, it'll be closed, if you opened it, it'll be open. Don't block the thread with a message box while the connection is open. Don't use `select *`, only select the columns you need. Use table aliases in queries.

Comment: The debugger tells you about the unhandled exception, no point in trying to keep running.  In general, you cannot ignore exceptions in code that accesses a database.  You **must** use try/catch to handle common mishaps.

Answer (score 0):

for your exception, i'm guessing is throwing this exception at this line :

```
    cbtaxrate.Text = r["taxrate"].ToString();
    txttax.Text = r["tax"].ToString();
```

because `r["taxrate"]` is not the same reader as `r1["adjustment"]`. So, i'm guessing you opened a reader with a name `r` in the same scope, then closed it, and opened a new reader `r1` and did the above code. the issue here is not about closing the reader connection, it's about following the best practices in handling instances and naming conversion. if you chose a readable naming for your variables, it will be easer for you to read and follow the code.

You need also to use `using` clause on disposable objects, for a better disposal handling.

Here is a helper method that would saves you the hassle:

```
public static class SqlConnectionHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string , object>> GetQueryValues(this SqlConnection connection , string sql , SqlParameter[] parameters , string[] fields)
    {
        if(connection == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(connection));
        }

        var mappedFields = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        using(var command = new SqlCommand(sql , connection))
        {
            if(parameters?.Length > 0)
            {
                command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
            }

            if(connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                connection.Open();

            using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if(reader.HasRows)
                    yield break;
                
                if(fields?.Length > 0)
                {
                    for(int x = 0; x < reader.FieldCount; x++)
                    {
                        var columnName = reader.GetName(x);
                        
                        if(Array.Exists(fields , i => i.Equals(columnName , StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
                        {
                            mappedFields.Add(x , columnName);
                        }
                    }
                    
                    while(reader.Read())
                    {
                        foreach(var field in mappedFields)
                        {
                            yield return new KeyValuePair<string , object>(field.Value , reader.GetValue(field.Key));
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                else
                {               
                    while(reader.Read())
                    {
                        for(int x = 0; x < reader.FieldCount; x++)
                        {                       
                            yield return new KeyValuePair<string , object>(reader.GetName(x) , reader.GetValue(x));
                        }
                    }
                
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public static Dictionary<string , object> GetQueryUniqueValues(this SqlConnection connection , string sql , SqlParameter[] parameters , string[] fields)
    {
        return GetQueryValues(connection , sql , parameters , fields)
        .GroupBy(x => x.Key)
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Name = x.Key ,
            Value = x.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Key == x.Key).Value
        })
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Name , x => x.Value);
    }   
}
```

with the reader helper, you can provide `fields` to get selected columns values, or you can just pass `null` to it and it will read all columns that have been provided under the `SELECT` statement.

reusing this to your current code would be like :

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    const string purchaseDetailsSql = "SELECT c.cust_name, c.cust_id, p.purchase_id, p.pdate, p.subtotal, p.total, p.supp_bill_id FROM Purchase_details p INNER JOIN customer c ON p.supplier_id = c.cust_id WHERE id = @id ;";
    
    const string purchasesSql = "SELECT adjustment, taxrate, tax FROM purchase WHERE purchase_id = @id ;";

    var parameters = new[]
    {
        new SqlParameter("@id", pd)
        {
             SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int
        }
    };
    
    var fields = new[] { "cust_name", "pdate" , "subtotal", "cust_id" };

    // here would select the columns from the provided fields array.
    var purchaseDetails = connection.GetQueryUniqueValues(purchaseDetailsSql , parameters, new[] { "cust_name", "pdate" , "subtotal", "cust_id" }); 

    // here would select the columns from the query.
    var purchases =  connection.GetQueryUniqueValues(purchasesSql, parameters, null);

    cbsupplier.Text = purchaseDetails["cust_name"]?.ToString();
    txtdate.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(purchaseDetails["pdate"]);
    txtsubtotal.Text = purchaseDetails["subtotal"]?.ToString();
    custid.Text = purchaseDetails["cust_id"]?.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show("pochalo");

    txtadjust.Text = purchases["adjustment"]?.ToString();
    cbtaxrate.Text = purchases["taxrate"]?.ToString();
    txttax.Text = purchases["tax"]?.ToString(); 
}
```